# How to set up a C++/WinRT class that accepts Win32 structs as method parameters

Tags: winapi, windows-runtime, c++-winrt, midl

I'm creating a desktop C++/WinRT project, and I'd like to declare a runtime class, using MIDL 3.0, that accepts certain Win32 types as method parameters.  For example, structs like `PROPERTYKEY`.

This isn't possible, however, as those aren't MIDL 3.0-compatible types, and from what I understand, they can't be packaged up as objects using `box_value` either.

I've gone through the documentation and searched at length, but I can't seem to locate a solution.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `PROPERTYKEY` is not a Windows Runtime type, but you can create your own equivalent. `struct PropertyKey { Guid Fmtid; UInt32 Pid; };`

Comment: And then would you recommend casting from one to the other?  Or would an assignment work?

Comment: You would have to do your own conversion. Note that the convention in the Windows Runtime is to pass property keys as strings. You can use `PSPropertyKeyFromString` to convert the string to a `PROPERTYKEY`.

Comment: Okay, thanks.  I have one last question: is there a way to pass an `IPropertyDescription` pointer to a WinRT class?  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: All objects passed into or out of the Windows Runtime must be based on IInspectable.